# Show a node (content) in a light box D7

Tags: 7, nodes, javascript

I need to show a video in a light box on a site and am having difficulty. I thought I would create a normal page with the proper code but when I go to load the video the screen grays out then goes and loads the page but gets stuck as if it cannot do it. I also tried just creating an html file and loading it directly but it couldn't read it or failed or something. I am using fancy box and html 5 if that matters.
How would I do this? If you need more info please let me know
Thanks for any help guys

Edit:
I have tried the solution below which is what i need it just isn't quite working yet.
the url of the node is: http://fourcemag.com/homme/video and http://www.fourcemag.com/homme/video-0/video
so the last part of the url is video

This is the code:

```
function fource_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $path = $_GET['q'];
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($path, $path_language = '');
  $patharray = explode('/', $path);

  if ($patharray[2] == 'video') {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page--video';
  }
}
```

This is the error:

[image]

- page--video.tpl.php

not sure what is wrong here.
Please help
Same error as before

Comment: The error you are getting is because it can not find the url arg "video-0", are you using the sef url? Try with "node/#/video-0"

Comment: I am using clean urls for seo so I cannot go back to the default urls. I tried eactly what you suggest but it still isn't working for the url: http://fourcemag.com/homme/video Based on what you suggest it should be working. What is wrong here.

Comment: Drupal will use 2 forms of URL, one which will be in the format of "/node/nodenumber" and the other will be the human readable search engine friendly url "category/article-name". Try the Drupal one and it should work. "fourcemag.com/node/46/video" just replace 46 with the actual number of the node

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without switching back to the default drupal urls...? My client is adamant about SEO friendly urls. There must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You will likely want to define a custom page.tpl.php for use in the lightbox so it doesnt conflict with your normal site pages where you would like sidebar content etc.

Think of having 2 differently themed versions of the same page, your traditional page and a cut down version which is only the node content area.

To do this, add a theme_preprocess_page() so it creates a unique url argument to trigger the content only display via its own tpl.php:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Get the path (eg node/#) and split it into an array ([node][#][video])
  $path = $_GET['q'];
  $path = drupal_get_path_alias($path, $path_language = '');
  $patharray = explode('/', $path);

  // If the last part of the path is "frame" use the page-content.tpl.php
  if ($patharray[2] == 'video') {
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'page--video';
  }
}
```

Then copy your exiting page.tpl.php into a page--video.tpl.php and trim out all the content you dont wish to see in your lightbox.

EDIT: (include details on using the video only page) In your iframe load your node page with "video" appended to the drupal url. For example **"node/135/video"** so it using the **page--video.tpl.php**

I have been using this solution to embed content from our nodes into another application and it works well. :)

Comment: Can you clarify what I should be filling in here? I underdstand YOURTTHEME but the rest not sure about. I need only over ride the tpl for the video node and any other video nodes in the future...

Comment: I'm getting an error on this line: if ($patharray[2] == 'resolve') {

Comment: I think you will have to do the page.tpl.php if you would like to use an iframe with no logo, menu, sidebar footer etc. My mistake on the error I left that in from my implementation. Updated my answer.

Comment: You can redefine "frame" and "page-content", frame is what would be used in the URL. While page-content is the template suggestion

Comment: Still not working for me... Same error. the url is http://fourcemag.com/homme/launch-video so I am using launch-video in place of frame. I am also using page-content as the suggestion. so page-content.tpl.php... should it be page--content.tpl.php...?

Comment: Ok I need to change the launch-video to video-0 or video-(any number) how do I do that for future videos. And still not working either way.

Comment: Ok, I think with the space it could complicate things, try just "video" initially then once it is working add the "launch-" part. So try the druapl url eg "node/222/" not the sef one (you could probably modify the code to work with a sef url) and append on "node/222/video". I will update my answer, looks like you are getting close!

Comment: I think it must be the sef url. How would I modify this to work with a sef url like the one shown? Are you using sef urls with your solution?

Comment: You can use both simultaneously, drupal always uses node/222/ it just displays a sef url to the user. Try it by going to the sef url and then finding the nid and using that in the other url

Answer (score 1):

I need also in a site to display a page as a pop up in a shadow box,I used a colorbox module because it give me option to open iframe (I don't know if light box can do it or not but I think color box is similar to light box) and I override the page.tpl.php to my page to remove all region except my content