# Drupal: node_load() in php file - load via ajax

Tags: nodes, ajax, database

i try to load a node in Drupal 7 in a php file, which will be loaded with ajax.

my php file looks like this:

```
require_once '../../../includes/bootstrap.inc';
$i = 16;
$content = node_load($i);
```

The include of bootstrap.inc works fine, but this file returns 'PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function node_load()'. i guess i've read that the function node_load needs the bootstrap.inc file, but it doesnt seems so.

Is there any possible way to use the node_load function right without 'register' a module in drupal - i just want to load a self made php file, which just returns the content of a node - without the template!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a custom php file you should attempt to solve the issue "the drupal way" via a custom module or in your template.php... Please see my answer in [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26831/show-a-node-content-in-a-light-box-d7/26861#26861).

It explains how you can add to the original url to change the template (or create a blank template so it is only node data presetned).

Comment: Arent there solutions to realize it without the template.php and without creating drupal-like functions ?

Comment: You can but then what would be the point of Drupal and its awesome framework / api. Using Drupal functions is really very easy, even more so than custom php once you are over the initial learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

> 7 node.module node_load($nid = NULL, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE)

node load [API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) is in node.module file. You probably need to include this file to get it working, but I suggest not to take this approach. If you dont want to write a separate module then add your functions to theme files. Its better to create a module or edit any existing modules and make a note that you have edited just in case you upgraded it then it will be over written.

Answer (score 0):

Please paste this code in the start of PHP file

```
<?php

    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

    require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
    ?>
```

Hope it will work!!